# How to install older version of node.js on Windows?

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I need to install node.js of version 4.0.0
I tried this:

```
npm install -g npm@4.0.0
```

But I got this message: npm is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Go [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/) and find the version you want to install and then download the correct msi file and run the installer.  You cannot install node by running this command, also the error you receive is stating that npm is not on your path which suggests machine doesn't currently have node installed on it

Comment: I am having problems finding the correct MSI file. I need to downgrade the Node version. Version 6.6.0 is having problems with Webstorm.

Comment: I have updated link as it has changed, all older versions are there.

Comment: there are no msi installers by the link that you provided. Only zip and 7z archives with bunch of executables and some other stuff but no .msi files

Comment: Updated link again, you need to click on the version number to find the msi you want.

Comment: When I try to install the MSI file ,it says "A later version of node is already install setup will now exit"

Comment: @Snedden27 if you want to install an older version of node you must uninstall the newer version before installing older version.

Comment: came here just to upvote this comment. the msi file was the crucial part for me, since i overlooked that when reading the comment the first time. Make sure you uninstall node first, then download the msi file. you should be able to get the installing wizard from there. You can also check what version you have installed in Control Panel. And close and previous command prompts you may have already open as re-running my version number command didnt work. open again as administrator. that fixed all my problems

Comment: there is no exe on the zip i downlaoded :(

Comment: Which zip did you download? Just tried it for latest and it worked

Comment: What do you mean by "run the installer"? where can I find the "installer"?

Comment: Download installer and once download has completed, click on the msi file and it will begin the installer program.

Answer (score 34):

Just uninstall whatever node version you have in your system.
Then go to this site 
https://nodejs.org/download/release/ 
and choose your desired version like for me its like v7.0.0/ and 
click on that go get **.msi** file of that.
Finally you will get installer in your system, so install it.
It will solve all your problems.

Comment:  Simple solution + good software management. Works as expected.

*In terms of time, the `nvm` answer above is most efficient.

Comment: To uninstall Node in the first instance (on Windows at least) search in Start for "Uninstall Node.js" and run the pre-prepared script

Answer (score 22):

For windows, best is: [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

1)install the .exe

2)restart (otherwise, nvm will not be undefined)

3)run CMD as admin,

4)nvm use 5.6.0

Note: You MUST run as Admin to switch node version every time.

Comment: Works like charm, thx! Ionic sass builde does not working well on the latest node windows version 10.6

Answer (score 12):

**run:**

> npm install -g node@7.10.1

```
- or whatever version you want after the @ symbol (This works as of 2019)
```

Answer (score 5):

At first, you will need to uninstall nodejs from the system preferably from Add or Remove Programs or Control Panel. Then, go to [nodejs](https://nodejs.org) official site, scroll down to find `previous releases` like in image 
[image]

click on `previous releases` and type in the version you are searching for in the search box 
[image]

Go to `downloads` and finally select a `msi` file from the list

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) for this purpose. [Download it from here.](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist/releases)

Usage:

```
nodist                         List all installed node versions.
nodist list
nodist ls

nodist <version>               Use the specified node version globally (downloads the executable, if necessary).
nodist latest                  Use the latest available node version globally (downloads the executable, if necessary).

nodist add <version>           Download the specified node version.
```

More Nodist commands [here](https://changelog.com/posts/nodist-node-version-manager-for-windows)

Answer (score 2):

If you are needing to downgrade/upgrade your node version, we need to ensure the below:

1. NVM is installed on your local machine.
2. NodeJs is installed on your local machine.

In your terminal, run the below command to verify your node version:

```
nvm list
```

Below you'll see different versions of node. However, if you do not see the version you require, we can run the below command:

Assume, we are wanting node version 14.17.1

```
nvm install 14.17.1
```

Once the download has completed, we are now able to select our node version:

```
nvm list
nvm use 14.17.1
```

To validate the node version change, we can run "nvm list".
The output will display a list of node versions, and the selected node version with an asterix (*) before the version.

Example: * 14.17.1 (Currently using 64-but executable)

Answer (score 0):

click here of this link  -
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/

and than select check your OS version for example- X64 bit
than click - node-v18.19.0-x64.msi download and install.

similar way for every version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35351246)