# React Does Not Creat App Mistake. How Do I Solve?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to start new React project but I have some mistakes that I've never seen it before. 
When I write my core

```
npx create-react-app appname
```

It should create as it normal way.

I already uninstalled and installed back.

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

But I see this mistake ; 
[PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDmdI.jpg)

CODE VERSION

```
npx create-react-app my-app
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files 
in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Here is my index.js code where error shows up ;

```
'use strict';

    var isPromise = require('is-promise');

    /**
     * Return a function that will run a function asynchronously or synchronously
     *
     * example:
     * runAsync(wrappedFunction, callback)(...args);
     *
     * @param   {Function} func  Function to run
     * @param   {Function} cb    Callback function passed the `func` returned value
     * @return  {Function(arguments)} Arguments to pass to `func`. This function will in turn
     *                                return a Promise (Node >= 0.12) or call the callbacks.
     */

    var runAsync = module.exports = function (func, cb) {
      cb = cb || function () {};

      return function () {

        var args = arguments;

        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          var resolved = false;
          const wrappedResolve = function (value) {
            if (resolved) {
              console.warn('Run-async promise already resolved.')
            }
            resolved = true;
            resolve(value);
          }

          var rejected = false;
          const wrappedReject = function (value) {
            if (rejected) {
              console.warn('Run-async promise already rejected.')
            }
            rejected = true;
            reject(value);
          }

          var usingCallback = false;
          var callbackConflict = false;
          var contextEnded = false;

          var answer = func.apply({
            async: function () {
              if (contextEnded) {
                console.warn('Run-async async() called outside a valid run-async context, callback will be ignored.');
                return function() {};
              }
              if (callbackConflict) {
                console.warn('Run-async wrapped function (async) returned a promise.\nCalls to async() callback can have unexpected results.');
              }
              usingCallback = true;
              return function (err, value) {
                if (err) {
                  wrappedReject(err);
                } else {
                  wrappedResolve(value);
                }
              };
            }
          }, Array.prototype.slice.call(args));

          if (usingCallback) {
            if (isPromise(answer)) {
              console.warn('Run-async wrapped function (sync) returned a promise but async() callback must be executed to resolve.');
            }
          } else {
            if (isPromise(answer)) {
              callbackConflict = true;
              answer.then(wrappedResolve, wrappedReject);
            } else {
              wrappedResolve(answer);
            }
          }
          contextEnded = true;
        });

        promise.then(cb.bind(null, null), cb);

        return promise;
      }
    };

    runAsync.cb = function (func, cb) {
      return runAsync(function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if (args.length === func.length - 1) {
          args.push(this.async());
        }
        return func.apply(this, args);
      }, cb);
    };
```

I would be very happy if I could get solution. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a recent problem with npm. There is an issue open as of the last few hours and it seems like people are working on it.

[The issue ticket](https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/13#issuecomment-619401394)

While the issue is being fixed: try installing node version 12.12.0 as shown below (if you have nvm installed)and run create-react-app again.

```
nvm install 12.12.0
nvm use 12.12.0
```

Comment: I use Windows 
So I get:nvm : The term 'nvm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, ve 
rify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nvm install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nvm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You'll have to install it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849714/how-to-install-older-version-of-node-js-on-windows

Comment: Amazing,Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Clear your npm-cache and:

```
npm i create-react-app
```

then

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Comment: after cleaning cache, install npm then npm i create-react-app,